Stable Higgs sheaf with many endomorphisms
Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over an algebraically closed field. If $\mathcal{E}$ is a stable sheaf, then $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathcal{E},\mathcal{E})=1$. But $(\mathcal{E},\theta)$ is only stable as a Higgs sheaf, not as a sheaf, then we may not have $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathcal{E},\mathcal{E})=1$ in a prior. Could anyone provide me an example that a stable Higgs sheaf with many endomorphisms?
